# Url builder function

Tags: javascript

```
const urlBuilder = params => {
  const { type, from, to } = params;
  return `http://random${type}link&start=${from}&end=${to}`;
}

const firstUrl = urlBuilder({
  type: first,
  from: 2,
  to: 3
})

const secondUrl = urBuilder({
  from: 4,
  to: 5
})
```

Lets say I want to create a reusable `urlBuilder` function, which I use to create 2 urls. The expected output would be:

For the firstUrl:

```
http://randomfirstlink&start=2&end=3
```

For the secondUrl:

```
http://randomlink&start=4&end=5
```

So basically if the `type` or any other parameter is not passed, it should return the string without that said parameter.

What is a good approach for this ?

Comment: What if there's no `from` or no `to`? Your example shows that if there's no `type`, the result is just without that `${type}`, would you want a function call without `from` to be, eg, `&start=&end=..`, or leave `&start=` off as well? Also, the object passed in `secondUrl` has `startDate` and `endDate`, not `from` and `to`, what does that signify?

Comment: If the returned output is invalid, I already have another function that throws an error. Basically only the `type` is optional, and if it is not passed, it should build the url, only without the `type` interpolated.

Comment: Then it seems like the `secondUrl` should throw an error, because there's no `from` nor a `to` property of the passed object?

Comment: @CertainPerformance My appologies, edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need the `type` to default to the empty string, when not provided in the passed object:

```js
const urlBuilder = params => {
  const { type = '', from, to } = params;
  //           ^^^^
  return `http://random${type}link&start=${from}&end=${to}`;
}

const firstUrl = urlBuilder({
  type: 'first',
  from: 2,
  to: 3
})

const secondUrl = urlBuilder({
  from: 4,
  to: 5
})
console.log(firstUrl);
console.log(secondUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just add some conditionals before build the value to return:

```js
// function declaration
const urlBuilder = params => {
  const { type = "", from = "", to = "" } = params; //added default values to prevent undefined
  let startString = (from === "" ? "" : `&start=${from}`); //if default value is present, nothing is inserted to the result
  let endString = (from === "" ? "" : `&end=${to}`);
  return `http://random${type}link${startString}${endString}`;
}

// test cases
const firstUrl = urlBuilder({
  type: 'first',
  from: 2,
  to: 3
});

const secondUrl = urlBuilder({
  from: 4,
  to: 5
});

const thirdUrl = urlBuilder({
  type: 'third'
});
// test output
console.log(firstUrl);
console.log(secondUrl);
console.log(thirdUrl);
```